# Ionic 4 cordova is not available when updating via Code Push

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, code-push

I am using Code Push cordova plugin for updating an Ionic 4 Cordova app. It used to work with Ionic 3 but since Ionic 4, Code Push is broken. The update seems to work but then Cordova is no longer available and therefore all native plugins are no longer working.

This is the command I am using to release an update:

```
appcenter codepush release-cordova -a [app_name] -d Staging --description "new update"
```

I am using the latest version of the `cordova-plugin-code-push` (1.12.0), ionic 4, angular 8, cordova-android 8.0.0.

What has changed and how can this plugin still be used? Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using `ionic cordova build android` instead of `ionic build` before running the CLI command to release the update.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's best to check on the update with the plugin itself and be able to pinpoint what the community has also encountered, check out:

https://github.com/microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push/issues'

it's not a straight answer but your error may be able to help also another developer when they encounter your issue.